# How to convert tree to list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Implement the predicate  treeToList(X,List), where X is a given ordered non-empty binary tree, and List is an ordered list of elements in nodes of the tree.

```
            4               
           / \
         2     6
        / \   / \ 
       1   3  5  7
```

is an ordered tree given as an input to predicate  "treeToList".
Your program must compute the list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

Here is the codes I had so far:

`treeToList(X,List) :- binaryTree(X), convert(X,List).`

`convert( tree(Element,void,void), List) :- List=[Element].`

The helping predicate convert(X,List) is true if X is a given non-empty tree, and List is a representation of this tree as an ordered list.

But I have no idea how to write the recursive part of this question

`convert( tree(Root,Left,Right), List) :-`

Can someone help me with this part?

Comment: How would you do that in a language like Java/C++/...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never explicitly said what your data structure looks like in Prolog, but I can infer that you have basically two kinds of tree node:

- `tree(Element, Left, Right)`
- `void`

To handle any recursive data structure, you write a recursive predicate. *Usually* (but not always) you want clauses for each kind of element. In Haskell, this is a bit more clear because you have to define your types and their constructors, but you can apply the same reasoning here. So your `convert/2` predicate is going to have a clause for each of your kinds of element:

```
convert(void, ...) :- ...
convert(tree(Element, Left, Right), ...) :- ...
```

You can see right away that the first clause is going to be pretty simple:

```
convert(void, []).
```

The second clause is where things get a bit more interesting. The key is to recursively apply `convert/2` to the subtrees on the left and right, and then you need to do something with the element you have:

```
convert(tree(Element, Left, Right), Rest) :-
    convert(Left, LeftList),
    convert(Right, RightList),
    append(LeftList, [Element|RightList], Rest).
```

Note that I'm prepending the current element to the right list before appending. This is to insert the element in its proper place in the list for an in-order traversal, to get you the result you want:

```
?- convert(tree(4, tree(2, tree(1, void, void), tree(3, void, void)),
                   tree(6, tree(5, void, void), tree(7, void, void))), 
           List).
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].
```

This gives you an in-order traversal. If you wanted a pre-order or a post-order traversal you would instead place the element in another position, such as at the start of the result or the end of the result.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! That's a very helpful answer to me.

Comment: @AllenLi glad I could help! Enjoy Prolog!

Comment: By the way, I have a question about the recursive part. Do we just go through the left subtree first and put all of them into a list then do the same thing to the right subtree, finally we append them together? Am I right?

Comment: @AllenLi Yes, that is what is happening there.

Answer (score 2):

Your tree has, based on the question, two "families" of data:

1. the constant `void`; and
2. a compound term with a `tree/3` with as arguments the value and the left and right subtree.

We can implement a predicate like [@DanielLyons demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160238/67579). We can slightly optimize this by defining a predicate `convert/3` where we the first parameter is the tree to convert, the second parameter is the head of the list, and the third parameter is the tail of the list.

We can thus define our predicate as:

```
convert(void, L, L).
convert(tree(V, L, R), H, T2) :-
    convert(L, H, [V|T1]),
    convert(R, T1, T2).
```

If we thus encounter a `void`, then the start and the end of the list remain the same. If we encounter a `tree(V, L, R)`, we will first recursively call `convert(L, H, [V|T1])`. By writing `[V|T1]` as tail, we thus force Prolog to yield the `V` value in the result. The tail `T1` is then the start of the `convert/3` of the second subtree.

We then can define `convert/2` in terms of `convert/3`:

```
convert(T, L) :-
    convert(T, L, []).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!